# How to send thousands of HTTP Requests using grerequests?

Tags: python, web-scraping, get, grequests

I need to request all the review pages for a company on Glassdoor, and in certain cases, there can be thousands of pages. I am trying to use `grequests` to do this, but I found that when I sent more than about 100 requests at once I would start to receive `403 error`.

I came up with this code to batch the requests into blocks of 100:

```
"reviews_url": "https://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/Apple-Reviews-E1138.htm?"

batch = 100
responses = []
for j in range(math.ceil(num_pages/batch)):
    print("Batching requests: {}/{}".format(min(num_pages, (j+1)*batch),num_pages))
    rs = (
        grequests.get(
            reviewsUrl.replace(".htm", "_P" + str(k + 1) + ".htm"),
            headers=DEFAULT_HEADERS,
        )
        for k in range(min(num_pages, (j)*batch), min(num_pages, (j+1)*batch))
    )
    responses += grequests.map(rs)
    time.sleep(uniform(10,15))
```

This works and I get what I need, but it is way too slow and I need to do this for ~8000 companies. Is there a better way to do this? I tried reducing the sleep time between batches and began getting 403's again.

Comment: I think they are putting some block on source ip, you need to check and mimic aCCORDINGLY

Comment: It sounds like the service is rate-limiting you. There may not be an easy way around that, unless you can distribute your work from multiple source IP addresses or authenticated users, which is probably against the terms of service for the site anyhow. So, your only real option is to obey the rate limit. You will probably find using [the API](https://www.glassdoor.com/developer/index.htm) will let you make more requests (and easier, too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Error 403](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) means that your request is okay, but that server refuses it. In your case, because you are making too many requests at the same time.

Webscrapping without timeouts (`time.sleep(uniform(10,15))`) abuses server resources and may impact service for other users. So most sites limit number of requests that you can do in some (short) timeframe. Server communicates that you went over this limit by sending you error 403. Sometimes servers also use [420](https://evertpot.com/http/420-enhance-your-calm) or [429](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429). Not obeying this message is at least impolite and commonly against terms of service.

**You can try:**

1. Do you really need to fetch data every time? Longer download time doesn't matter if you need to do it only once (for example saving data to csv file and reading from it later).
2. Increasing timeout between requests.
3. Check if website offers some way to download data in bulk (did you try [Glassdoor api](https://www.glassdoor.com/developer/index.htm))?

Comment: Yes, this data collection is one time only but currently it would take about 8 days to complete. I'd like to speed this up in some way, I was thinking perhaps the Threadpool executor could help me.

Also, the Glassdoor API is not taking any new registrations so that will not help me.

Comment: Concurrency won't help you, since server is throttling your IP - it's slow because they slow you down, not because one thread is not enough.